# Not able to change shipping Region Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am New on Magento and working on magento1.9. On the front page of the website when i am trying to change shipping address Name, address fields are updating, But Region in not updating.Flat rate US$25.00 is set from admin.

I am following steps below:

Step-1. From the admin Area i have done settings.

[image]

Step-2

[image]

Front end image.

[image]

By default only Californiya is comming, It is not updating. If is change setting from admin "Apply Default to empty quote" to No. Than Flate rate US$25.00 does not includes in cart. Please help..

Thanks